# Non-overlapping rolling windows in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am familiar with the Pandas Rolling window functions, but they always have a step size of 1. I want to do a moving aggregate function in Pandas, but where the entries don't overlap.

In this Dataframe: [image]

```
df.rolling(2).min()
```

will yield:

`N/A 519 566 727 1099 12385`

But I want a fixed window with a step size of 2, so it yields:

`519 727 12385`

Because with a fixed window, it should step over by the size of that window instead.

Comment: Where are the averages in your example?

Comment: I did a `min()` here because the numbers are big, so its easier to illustrate what I am looking for. With an average, I still want a fixed-window aggregate function.

Comment: Are you asking `df.groupby(np.arrange(0,len(df),2)//2).min)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no such built in argument in the `rolling` function, but you can compute the usual rolling function and then skip every `n`th row (where `n=2` in your case).

```
df.rolling(n).min()[n-1::n]
```

As you mentioned in your comment, this might result in many redudant computations which will be ignored (especially if `n` is large).
Instead, you could use the following code which partitions (groups) the data into bins of size `n`:

```
df.groupby(df.index // n).min()
```

I did not check if it's indeed more efficient, but I believe it should be.

Comment: The problem is that on a large dataframe, it will be doing a lot of extra computation that will end up being discarded.

Comment: You are correct. It will also become more significant if the sliding window width will be larger.

Comment: The second method worked really well. I did a time check on both computations:

Comment: `Wall time: 2min 32s` for `rolling()` and `Wall time: 7.08s` for the `groupby()`. This is on a Dataframe with 1602661 rows.

Comment: Great. for n=2?

Comment: Actually n = 1000, because of the size of the DF (1602661 rows). The aggregate function I used is also a `lambda` so a `mean()` would probably be even faster.

Comment: Careful: This also assumes the index is integer and continuous.