# How to calculate basic statistics for every 20 data points in a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWmpz.png)

I have a data frame which similar as shown in the picture, I have more than 400 data points. Is there any simple way I can calculate the basic statistics of every 10 data points by using python?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a loop where each iteration you perform the calculations on a chunk of 10 elements.

Comment: Or, you can add another column, `group_id`, which you assign a number (1 for the first 10 items, 2 for the next 10, etc), then use the functions [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to perform calculations on each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a counter to count the number of visited rows in an iteration. when is 10, perform your desire actions: (You can store the visited rows somewhere like a list)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
count = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if count == 10:
        ## do basic statistics 
        count = 0
    else:
        ## store the desire value for calculation
        count += 1
```

Comment: thankyou! can I ask one more question on how can I see the desired value of each basic statistics calculation?

Comment: if you mean the cell value in dataframe, you can use row['column_name'] inside the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

use pandas rolling function
`df.rolling(window=10).sum()` or any method

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [Non-overlapping rolling windows in pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595661/non-overlapping-rolling-windows-in-pandas-dataframes)

You can use `pandas.rolling`, or group by index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(40,1)),
            columns = ['A'])

df.groupby(df.index//10).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

Output

[image]